# QML how to get the position of Loader

Tags: qt, qml, loader

I want generate a binary tree like flow to show organization relationship info with QML.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrBk5.png)

My way:

1. Create tree node like flow example.
2. Line the tree nodes with Canvas like above picture. I want get the
   point and draw line after Loader.onLoaded.

My question:

After the first step has been done. In the second step, I can't get the right position point of the tree node.

Details:

According to Qt document, if I don't set the width and height of Loader explicitly, it will automatically set by its item size. However, I can't get the node position point in `Loader.onloaded()`

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: appWindow

    visible: true
    width: 1066
    height: 600

    property var jsonData: [{"id":1,"pid":0},{"id":2,"pid":1},{"id":3,"pid":1},
        {"id":4,"pid":2},{"id":5,"pid":2},{"id":6,"pid":3},
        {"id":7,"pid":3},{"id":8,"pid":4},{"id":9,"pid":4},{"id":10,"pid":6}]
    property int maxRectangles: 5
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var color = Qt.lighter("red", maxRectangles / 7)
        pLoader.sourceComponent = rectangleComponent;
        var currItem = pLoader.item;
        currItem.color = "blue"
        currItem.text = 0

        var tmp = {};
        tmp[jsonData[0]["id"]] = currItem ;

        for(var index = 1; index < jsonData.length; index++) {
            color = Qt.lighter("red", index / 7)
            var sItem = jsonData[index]["pid"];
            if(tmp[sItem].rComponent.sourceComponent === null){
                tmp[sItem].rComponent.sourceComponent = rectangleComponent
                attachData(tmp[sItem].rComponent.item,index, color);
                tmp[jsonData[index]["id"]] = tmp[sItem].rComponent.item ;
            }
            else {
                tmp[sItem].lComponent.sourceComponent = rectangleComponent
                attachData(tmp[sItem].lComponent.item,index, color);
                tmp[jsonData[index]["id"]] = tmp[sItem].lComponent.item ;
            }
        }
    }
    function attachData(item, text, color){
        item.text = text;
        item.color = color
    }

    Component {
        id: rectangleComponent
        Column{
            property alias rComponent: rightLoader
            property alias lComponent: leftLoader
            property alias color: rect.color
            property alias text: myText.text
            spacing: 40
            //anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Rectangle {
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                id:rect
                width: 100
                height: 100
                Text{
                    id:myText
                    font.pixelSize: 18
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    color:"white"
                }
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Component.onCompleted", mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0))
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        updateDotPosition(parent)
                        //here, printed coordinate is my expected
                        //but i want line them after tree node loaded antomate
                        console.log("updateDotPosition", mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0))
                    }
                }
            }

            Row{
                spacing: 40
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                Loader {
                    id:leftLoader
                    onLoaded: {
                        console.log("leftLoader", mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0))
                    }
                }
                Loader {
                    id:rightLoader
                    onLoaded: {
                        console.log("rightLoader", mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Canvas{
        anchors.fill: parent
        id:canvas
        Loader {
            id:pLoader
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            //sourceComponent: rectangleComponent
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: testMapToItemDot
        width: 20
        height: width
        radius: width / 2
        z: 1
        color: "darkblue"
    }

    function updateDotPosition(itemToMap) {
        var pos = testMapToItemDot.mapFromItem(
                    itemToMap,
                    (itemToMap.width - testMapToItemDot.width) / 2,   // these parameters are optional - I want to move the dot to
                    (itemToMap.height - testMapToItemDot.height) / 2) // the center of the object, not upper left corner
        testMapToItemDot.x += pos.x
        testMapToItemDot.y += pos.y
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position and size of the loaded item can be accessed like this: `Loader.item.x`, `Loader.item.y`, `Loader.item.width`, `Loader.item.height`.

If this is not what your are looking for please describe the question more precisely.

---

Please have a look at this example application. I think it is what you are looking for - have a look at `function updateDotPosition(itemToMap)`. Please note that if you will be "mapping" to an object that is not moving (dot in the example is moving) and this object will be a sibling of the `Canvas` with the same `x`, `y` values then the result of the function will give you exact points where from and where to draw a line. You will not need to use `+=` as I used.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: appWindow

    visible: true
    width: 1066
    height: 600

    property int maxRectangles: 5

    Component {
        id: rectangleComponent
        Rectangle {
            x: 110
            y: 30
            width: 100
            height: 100
            property var loaderSource
            Component.onCompleted: {
                color = Qt.lighter("red", maxRectangles / 7)
                if (maxRectangles-- > 0)
                    loaderSource = rectangleComponent
                else
                    loaderSource = undefined
            }
            Loader {
                sourceComponent: loaderSource
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    updateDotPosition(parent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Loader {
        sourceComponent: rectangleComponent
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: testMapToItemDot
        width: 20
        height: width
        radius: width / 2
        z: 1
        color: "darkblue"
    }

    function updateDotPosition(itemToMap) {
        var pos = testMapToItemDot.mapFromItem(
                    itemToMap,
                    (itemToMap.width - testMapToItemDot.width) / 2,   // these parameters are optional - I want to move the dot to
                    (itemToMap.height - testMapToItemDot.height) / 2) // the center of the object, not upper left corner
        testMapToItemDot.x += pos.x
        testMapToItemDot.y += pos.y
    }
}
```

---

Here is working version of your example. This is just an example. Dirty one unfortunately. This is because it was a little hard for me to understand what is going on in the code - I am sure you will not have this problem. Also I have used `Timer` because the `Rectangle` objects on creation have `x,y` equal to `0`. I needed to wait a bit. Please do not use this in release code - it is bad design :)

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: appWindow

    visible: true
    width: 1066
    height: 600

    property var jsonData: [{"id":1,"pid":0},{"id":2,"pid":1},{"id":3,"pid":1},
        {"id":4,"pid":2},{"id":5,"pid":2},{"id":6,"pid":3},
        {"id":7,"pid":3},{"id":8,"pid":4},{"id":9,"pid":4},{"id":10,"pid":6}]
    property int maxRectangles: 5
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var color = Qt.lighter("red", maxRectangles / 7)
        pLoader.sourceComponent = rectangleComponent;
        var currItem = pLoader.item;
        currItem.color = "blue"
        currItem.text = 0
        connectedItems.push([currItem, null])

        var tmp = {};
        tmp[jsonData[0]["id"]] = currItem ;

        for(var index = 1; index < jsonData.length; index++) {
            color = Qt.lighter("red", index / 7)
            var sItem = jsonData[index]["pid"];
            if(tmp[sItem].rComponent.sourceComponent === null){
                tmp[sItem].rComponent.sourceComponent = rectangleComponent
                attachData(tmp[sItem].rComponent.item,index, color);
                tmp[jsonData[index]["id"]] = tmp[sItem].rComponent.item ;
                connectedItems.push([tmp[sItem].rComponent.item, null])
            }
            else {
                tmp[sItem].lComponent.sourceComponent = rectangleComponent
                attachData(tmp[sItem].lComponent.item,index, color);
                tmp[jsonData[index]["id"]] = tmp[sItem].lComponent.item ;
                connectedItems.push([tmp[sItem].lComponent.item, null])
            }
            if ( jsonData[index]["pid"] !== 0) {
                connectedItems[connectedItems.length - 1][1] = connectedItems[jsonData[index]["pid"] - 1][0]
            }
        }
    }
    function attachData(item, text, color){
        item.text = text;
        item.color = color
    }

    property var connectedItems: [];

    function paintConnection(objectFrom, objectTo) {
        var vectorStart = canvas.mapFromItem(
                    objectFrom, objectFrom.width / 2, objectFrom.height)

        var vectorEnd = canvas.mapFromItem(
                    objectTo, objectTo.width / 2,0)

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(vectorStart.x, vectorStart.y);
        ctx.lineTo(vectorEnd.x,vectorEnd.y);
        ctx.stroke();

        canvas.requestPaint()
    }

    Timer {
        id: paintLines
        interval: 100
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            for (var i = 1 ; i < connectedItems.length ; i++) {
                paintConnection(connectedItems[i][1].rect, connectedItems[i][0].rect)
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: rectangleComponent
        Column{
            property alias rComponent: rightLoader
            property alias lComponent: leftLoader
            property alias color: rect.color
            property alias text: myText.text
            property alias rect: rect
            spacing: 40
            //anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Rectangle {
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                id:rect
                width: 100
                height: 100
                Text{
                    id:myText
                    font.pixelSize: 18
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    color:"white"
                }
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Component.onCompleted", mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0))
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        updateDotPosition(parent)
                        //here, printed coordinate is my expected
                        //but i want line them after tree node loaded antomate
                        console.log("updateDotPosition", mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0))
                    }
                }
            }

            Row{
                spacing: 40
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                Loader {
                    id:leftLoader
                    onLoaded: {
                        console.log("leftLoader", mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0))
                    }
                }
                Loader {
                    id:rightLoader
                    onLoaded: {
                        console.log("rightLoader", mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Canvas{
        anchors.fill: parent
        id:canvas
        Loader {
            id:pLoader
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            //sourceComponent: rectangleComponent
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: testMapToItemDot
        width: 20
        height: width
        radius: width / 2
        z: 1
        color: "darkblue"
    }

    function updateDotPosition(itemToMap) {
        var pos = testMapToItemDot.mapFromItem(
                    itemToMap,
                    (itemToMap.width - testMapToItemDot.width) / 2,   // these parameters are optional - I want to move the dot to
                    (itemToMap.height - testMapToItemDot.height) / 2) // the center of the object, not upper left corner
        testMapToItemDot.x += pos.x
        testMapToItemDot.y += pos.y
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I generate tree use recursion way. so Loader.item.x and y is the parent's coordinate(like Row or Column).
I expect get coordinate of Canvas for drawLine, so I use mapToItem(canvas, 0, 0) transfor it.
My question is I can't get the right coordinate.

Comment: @user6391639 I have updated my answer. Please have a look at the code I provided. I think it works as you wish.

Comment: thanks very much, I have update my description and update my example with your example. I hope load tree node and line them.expect for your answer, thanks again.

Comment: @user6391639 You are welcome. I have updated my answer and added working version of your example.

Comment: I thought every thing is on ready while Component.onCompleted triggered once.
But,beacuse of used Column and Row for layout automatically in my scence. The parent node will replacement while sub-node be loaded. So I can't get the right position point in onCompleted() or onloaded() triggered.
I think set the node site by myself manually much better in this scence now.
Thanks again very much.非常感谢！